# Hibernate many to many mapping for multiple relationships between two entities with linking table

Tags: java, hibernate, entity-relationship

I work on an application for bike hire, with the relations looking as following:

[image]

So the basic premise is that a registered user can both offer his bike for hire and hire someone's bike, and the bike, in turn, can appear both in an offer and as a hire (I will place some checks in place to make sure that the bike is either available or in in hire, but not both at the same time).

My Hibernate is rubbish, so I'm looking for a sensible objects mapping to handle the above scenario. So far I imagine the class structure to look something like this:

```java
@Entity(name = "user")
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID id;
    ...
}
```

```java
@Entity(name = "bike")
@Table(name = "bike")
public class Bike {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID id;
    ...
}
```

```java
@Entity(name = "bike_offer")
@Table(name = "bike_offer")
public class BikeOffer {
    @OneToOne()
    private User lender;
    @OneToMany
    private Bike bike;
    ...
}
```

```java
@Entity(name = "bike_hire")
@Table(name = "bike_hire")
public class BikeHire {
    @OneToOne()
    private User lender;
    @OneToMany
    private Bike bike;
    ...
}
```

I can see right away that isn't gonna work as I'll need to specify @JoinTable for @OneToOne and @OneToMany relationships, but I'm not sure which one to specify as I'm already declaring both `BikeOffer` and `BikeHire` as relationships with tables.

And so I'm stuck. Any suggestions on how that double-relationship could be untangled as entities?

Comment: `BikeHire extends User` means that a BikeHire IS a User. Bike and User should not be abstract. The User class (or the Bike class, or both)should also have a collection of BikeHire and a collection BikeOffer.

Comment: Thank you Guillaume, actually the abstract classes and BikeHire extends User are copy and paste mistakes. I've edited my post to iron out these niggles. And thank you - your suggestion actually put me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Guillaume, here's the solution. It's all in the User class:

```
@Entity(name = "bike")
@Table(name = "bike")
public class Bike {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID id;
    ...
}    

@Entity(name = "user")
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID id;
    ...
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "bike_offer",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="bike_offer_user_id")),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "bike_id", foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="bike_offer_bike_id"))
    )
    private Set<Bike> bikeOffers;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "bike_hire",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="bike_hire_user_id")),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "bike_id", foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="bike_hire_bike_id"))
    )
    private Set<Bike> bikeHires;
```